# Correct implementation of Logistic Regression Model

Tags: logistic

I am trying to follow the methodology shown here:

http://beyondmicrofoundations.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/logisitic-regression-and-stock-returns.html

Q1.) Is this methodology correct?

Q.2) Have I implemented it correctly in Matlab?

```
 rtn=(Data1.Mid(2:end)-Data1.Mid(1:end-1))./(Data1.Mid(1:end-1));

 NStep=1;

Up=nan(length(rtn),1);
Down=nan(length(rtn),1);
Flat=nan(length(rtn),1);
RtnClass=nan(length(rtn),1);

for i=1:length(rtn)-NStep

   if(rtn(i+NStep)>0)
       Up(i)=2;
       Down(i)=1;
       Flat(i)=1;
    elseif(rtn(i+NStep)<0)
       Up(i)=1;
       Down(i)=2;
       Flat(i)=1;
    elseif(rtn(i+NStep)==0)
       Up(i)=1;
       Down(i)=1;
       Flat(i)=2;
    end

end

[BUp,dev,stats] = mnrfit(rtn,Up);
MatProbUp = mnrval(BUp,0);

[BDown,dev,stats] = mnrfit(rtn,Down);
MatProbDown = mnrval(BDown,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you want to know, BUT, since your response is ordinal:  down < unchanged < up, you might be better off using [ordinal logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit) instead of multinomial logistic regression.  [It can be run in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/polr.html).